# What is too CPU intensive in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

How do you know whether a piece of code will be too CPU intensive on a node js server? Perhaps I'm not understanding node.js enough, but wouldn't even minor calculations build up too much after many connections are open? Why dont the number of clients always eventually become a bottleneck?

What prompts me to ask this question was this blog post: http://blog.artillery.com/2012/05/realtime-multiplayer-3d-gaming-html5.html

Artillery uses a node.js server, and chooses to run the computations and game simulator on said server. These are CPU intensive operations. After a certain amount of clients, doesn't this become a problem? Why would intense game development in node be possible in the first place if this is true? Am I missing something? Is Artillery just doing something very special and unique to enable this?

In short, the one thing that worries me about moving to node.js is that I'm confused at what amount of computation qualifies as an operation that is TOO blocking. It seems that even simple tasks would eventually become worrisome.

Comment: MAX_NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS = MAX_CPU_PERFORMANCE / CPU_PER_CALCULATION / OPERATIONS_PER_CLIENT. At *some* point this always becomes a problem. Until then, it just scales quite well.

Comment: So basically I should just do my best to decrease how CPU intensive the application is, and as long as I scale up my hardware and dont do anything too crazy I should be fine?

Comment: Yes, that's how programming server applications works :-)